# my Custom bootloader not working

Tags: boot, usb, bootloader

I have designed my custom bootloader (which showy my name only.) using assembly language and compiled it using NASM. Now i want to install it in USB.but not able to find any way for burning it. I have tested using different utilities like ISOtoUSB, Universal USB,rufus. Error is coming 'image is not bootable.'

But when i run the same on oracle virtual drive, it works perfectly.

I am doing some college project and strucked, i want to load that bootloader to usb and when i boot from usb, my bootloader should work..

Any idea please ???

Comment: Please help, i searching on google since long, i have tried to burn ISO to USB, but no success, any try please...